# SQL query logging for SQLite?

Tags: sql, logging, sqlite

I need to log queries, not only inserts/updates/deletes but also selects and other queries, from a number of applications that use SQLite. Introducing logging to the applications would in this case not be a feasible solution in practice. So how can I enable query logging in SQLite itself?

Comment: Just to add a bit more info, if you're using SQLite in your application, you should probably use a different logging system for the app as a whole, rather than asking for built-in SQLite functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the sqlite [Trace](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) API. You have to implement the callback yourself.

```
void *sqlite3_trace(sqlite3*, void(*xTrace)(void*,const char*), void*);
```

> The callback function registered by `sqlite3_trace()` is invoked at various times when an SQL statement is being run by `sqlite3_step()`. The callback returns a UTF-8 rendering of the SQL statement text as the statement first begins executing. Additional callbacks occur as each triggered subprogram is entered.

Comment: Ok, so you are basically saying that I would need to write the code for logging. I wonder if someone has already done that, for a common use case like this?

Comment: You have to write the COMMAND to invoke the **inbuilt** trace mechanism.

Comment: The sqlite3_trace api doesn't show you bindings.  If your using a wrapper class, you may want to put in your own logging of the sql statements and the parameters.

Comment: Just wanted to drop in a small snippet for basic logging :  void trace_callback( void* udp, const char* sql ) {
    printf("{SQL} [%s]\n", sql);
} sqlite3_trace(g_dbConf, trace_callback, NULL);

Comment: Quite hard to write - my basic attempt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410173/could-sqlite3-generate-non-deterministic-errors