# How can I log queries in Sqlite3 with Python?

Tags: python, logging, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite3 database in my Python application and query it using parameters substitution.
For example:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ?', (10,))
```

Some queries do not return results properly and I would like to log them and try to query sqlite manually.
How can I log these queries with parameters instead of question marks?

Comment: Looks similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607368/sql-query-logging-for-sqlite) question, though that example doesn't specify Python. See if it helps.

Answer (score 40):

Python 3.3 has [sqlite3.Connection.set_trace_callback](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_trace_callback):

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
connection.set_trace_callback(print)
```

The function you provide as argument gets called for every SQL statement that is executed through that particular Connection object. Instead of `print`, you may want to use a function from the `logging` module.

Comment: Will that log query info for all queries or just for those of my own app?

Comment: It’ll log only those queries made through that particular Connection object (`connection` above). I’ve update the answer.

Comment: If you're using the logging infrastructure it's worth noting you can replace "print" with say "logging.debug" seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a log function, you could call it first :

```
query, param = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ?', (10,)
log(query.replace('?', '%s') % param)
cursor.execute(query, param)
```

So you **don't modify your query** at all.

Moreover, this is not Sqlite specific.

Comment: This will produce wrong results. Sqlite will escape your data when it contains strings

Comment: Strings are immutable. This can work. @balrok

Comment: String .replace() does not escape sqlite statement parameters correctly, with respect to quoting and other considerations.