# Switching off sqlite3_trace from tracing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607368/sql-query-logging-for-sqlite) question I finally managed to enable sqlite3_trace in my iPhone application.

Now, I have noticed that after being enabled, sqlite traces every statement, even outside the scope of the function I have enabled it.

Not much of a trouble but I am wondering whether there is a way to switch it off for other statements leaving it on for some specific ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you call sqlite3_trace again and pass NULL for the callback function-pointer, then that should disable tracing.