# Could sqlite3 generate non-deterministic errors?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am getting random errors when saving and reading data in Sqlite3 database (VS 2015 Express test).

Made simple trace and can see there is something a bit modified read by select after update sometimes, but not sure where it comes from or what is reason.
Sometimes they are frequent, but now they are very rare - last time 2 times different uint8_t values during few manual runs of same testcase in a short time for example...

How can I check what is causing this - DB / FS / sqlite3.c problem or something else ?

*I am testing on a 3 month old NTB having single SSD drive only.*

My tracing code:

**sqlite3_trace_v2(database, SQLITE_TRACE_STMT | SQLITE_TRACE_ROW, DBtrace::Trace, 0);**

```
class DBtrace {
public:
    static bool logNow;
    static std::string log;

    DBtrace(bool enable = false) { logNow = enable; }

    DBtrace & DBtrace::Instance()
    {
        static DBtrace  instance;
        return instance;
    }

    static int Trace(unsigned int d, void *m, void *p, void *x);
};

#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "db_trace.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

namespace databaseNS
{
    bool DBtrace::logNow;
    std::string DBtrace::log;

    static int isUseless(int c) { return c < 32; }
    bool BothAreSpaces(char lhs, char rhs) { return (lhs == rhs) && (lhs < 32); }

    int DBtrace::Trace(unsigned int d, void *m, void *p, void *x) {
        if (!logNow) return 0;
        string sql;
        std::string::iterator new_end;
        sqlite3_value *v;
        sqlite3_stmt *pStmt = reinterpret_cast<sqlite3_stmt *>(p);
        int cc = sqlite3_column_count(pStmt);
        switch (d)
        {
        case SQLITE_TRACE_STMT:
            sql = sqlite3_expanded_sql(pStmt);
            new_end = std::unique(sql.begin(), sql.end(), BothAreSpaces);
            sql.erase(new_end, sql.end());
            sql += "\r\n";
            log += sql;
            break;

        case SQLITE_TRACE_ROW:
            int n = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(pStmt);
            for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++)
            {
                sql = sqlite3_column_name(pStmt, i);
                v = sqlite3_column_value(pStmt, i);
                if (v->flags & MEM_Int) {
                    sql += ":" + std::to_string(v->u.i) + ", ";
                    log += sql;
                }
                if (v->flags & MEM_Str) {
                    sql += ":";
                    sql += v->z;
                    sql += ", ";
                    log += sql;
                };
            }
            log += "\r\n";
            break;

        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

And a lot of required declarations found in sqlite3.c (*db_trace.hpp*)

```
#include <string>

   /**
   * @brief Routine for preparation sql queries needed for data handling
   *
   * @return true if success, false otherwise
   *
   */
   /*
   ** Integers of known sizes.  These typedefs might change for architectures
   ** where the sizes very.  Preprocessor macros are available so that the
   ** types can be conveniently redefined at compile-type.  Like this:
   **
   **         cc '-DUINTPTR_TYPE=long long int' ...
   */
#ifndef UINT32_TYPE
# ifdef HAVE_UINT32_T
#  define UINT32_TYPE uint32_t
# else
#  define UINT32_TYPE unsigned int
# endif
#endif
#ifndef UINT16_TYPE
# ifdef HAVE_UINT16_T
#  define UINT16_TYPE uint16_t
# else
#  define UINT16_TYPE unsigned short int
# endif
#endif
#ifndef INT16_TYPE
# ifdef HAVE_INT16_T
#  define INT16_TYPE int16_t
# else
#  define INT16_TYPE short int
# endif
#endif
#ifndef UINT8_TYPE
# ifdef HAVE_UINT8_T
#  define UINT8_TYPE uint8_t
# else
#  define UINT8_TYPE unsigned char
# endif
#endif
#ifndef INT8_TYPE
# ifdef HAVE_INT8_T
#  define INT8_TYPE int8_t
# else
#  define INT8_TYPE signed char
# endif
#endif
#ifndef LONGDOUBLE_TYPE
# define LONGDOUBLE_TYPE long double
#endif
typedef sqlite_int64 i64;          /* 8-byte signed integer */
typedef sqlite_uint64 u64;         /* 8-byte unsigned integer */
typedef UINT32_TYPE u32;           /* 4-byte unsigned integer */
typedef UINT16_TYPE u16;           /* 2-byte unsigned integer */
typedef INT16_TYPE i16;            /* 2-byte signed integer */
typedef UINT8_TYPE u8;             /* 1-byte unsigned integer */
typedef INT8_TYPE i8;              /* 1-byte signed integer */
typedef struct FuncDef FuncDef;
struct sqlite3_value {
    union MemValue {
        double r;           /* Real value used when MEM_Real is set in flags */
        i64 i;              /* Integer value used when MEM_Int is set in flags */
        int nZero;          /* Extra zero bytes when MEM_Zero and MEM_Blob set */
        const char *zPType; /* Pointer type when MEM_Term|MEM_Subtype|MEM_Null */
        FuncDef *pDef;      /* Used only when flags==MEM_Agg */
    } u;
    u16 flags;          /* Some combination of MEM_Null, MEM_Str, MEM_Dyn, etc. */
    u8  enc;            /* SQLITE_UTF8, SQLITE_UTF16BE, SQLITE_UTF16LE */
    u8  eSubtype;       /* Subtype for this value */
    int n;              /* Number of characters in string value, excluding '\0' */
    char *z;            /* String or BLOB value */
                        /* ShallowCopy only needs to copy the information above */
    char *zMalloc;      /* Space to hold MEM_Str or MEM_Blob if szMalloc>0 */
    int szMalloc;       /* Size of the zMalloc allocation */
    u32 uTemp;          /* Transient storage for serial_type in OP_MakeRecord */
    sqlite3 *db;        /* The associated database connection */
    void(*xDel)(void*);/* Destructor for Mem.z - only valid if MEM_Dyn */
#ifdef SQLITE_DEBUG
    Mem *pScopyFrom;    /* This Mem is a shallow copy of pScopyFrom */
    u16 mScopyFlags;    /* flags value immediately after the shallow copy */
#endif
};
/* One or more of the following flags are set to indicate the validOK
** representations of the value stored in the Mem struct.
**
** If the MEM_Null flag is set, then the value is an SQL NULL value.
** For a pointer type created using sqlite3_bind_pointer() or
** sqlite3_result_pointer() the MEM_Term and MEM_Subtype flags are also set.
**
** If the MEM_Str flag is set then Mem.z points at a string representation.
** Usually this is encoded in the same unicode encoding as the main
** database (see below for exceptions). If the MEM_Term flag is also
** set, then the string is nul terminated. The MEM_Int and MEM_Real
** flags may coexist with the MEM_Str flag.
*/
#define MEM_Null      0x0001   /* Value is NULL (or a pointer) */
#define MEM_Str       0x0002   /* Value is a string */
#define MEM_Int       0x0004   /* Value is an integer */
#define MEM_Real      0x0008   /* Value is a real number */
#define MEM_Blob      0x0010   /* Value is a BLOB */
#define MEM_AffMask   0x001f   /* Mask of affinity bits */
/* Available          0x0020   */
/* Available          0x0040   */
#define MEM_Undefined 0x0080   /* Value is undefined */
#define MEM_Cleared   0x0100   /* NULL set by OP_Null, not from data */
#define MEM_TypeMask  0xc1ff   /* Mask of type bits */
```

Comment: Please never use the term "random error". Try for example (a combination of) "unexpected error", "unfamiliar error", "non-deterministic error", "non-reproducable error", etc, based on what's most appropriate for you.

Comment: I expect the answer to the title is very likely not. I do use sqlite in many of my work applications for over a decade and have never experienced any odd error behavior. However I use it in Qt so I am not using it directly.

Comment: Non-deterministic behavior is the major symptom of concurrency issues. I would start looking at this first. Next major problem causing this behavior is the memory management. Check if you have *dangling* pointers of you are overflowing the buffers. Also check if the sqlite3 library version you are using has a known defect with this manifestation.

Comment: You are probably right - there are some non-atomic operations like read current value, compare and only in case it is different write it - in thread world having single DB this cannot work properly ;-) Anyway it it is good to have multiple testcase that can generate such a problem to mind how simply something can break sometimes...